# Что делать, если не понятна логика работы кода (что происходит "под капотом")?

Tags: python, рекурсия, факториал

Объясните, пожалуйста, логику кода. Мне не понятно то, что происходит "под капотом":

```
def F(n):
    if n > 2:
        return F(n-1)+ G(n-2)
    else: return 1
def G(n):
    if n > 2:
        return G(n-1) + F(n-2)
    else: return 1
print(F(7))
```

Если возможно, распишите пожалуйста поэтапно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте отладочную информацию - так станет немного понятнее:

```
def F(n):
    if n > 2:
        print(f"F({n}): calling F({n-1}) + G({n-2})")
        return F(n-1)+ G(n-2)
    else:
        print(f"G({n}): return 1")
        return 1

def G(n):
    if n > 2:
        print(f"G({n}): calling G({n-1}) + F({n-2})")
        return G(n-1) + F(n-2)
    else:
        print(f"G({n}): return 1")
        return 1

print(F(7))
```

Вывод:

```
F(7): calling F(6) + G(5)
F(6): calling F(5) + G(4)
F(5): calling F(4) + G(3)
F(4): calling F(3) + G(2)
F(3): calling F(2) + G(1)
G(2): return 1
G(1): return 1
G(2): return 1
G(3): calling G(2) + F(1)
G(2): return 1
G(1): return 1
G(4): calling G(3) + F(2)
G(3): calling G(2) + F(1)
G(2): return 1
G(1): return 1
G(2): return 1
G(5): calling G(4) + F(3)
G(4): calling G(3) + F(2)
G(3): calling G(2) + F(1)
G(2): return 1
G(1): return 1
G(2): return 1
F(3): calling F(2) + G(1)
G(2): return 1
G(1): return 1
13
```

Comment: Но с ручкой надёжнее, мне кажется, для понимания и запоминания ))  Так то да, отладочная печать рулит.

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен! Но я, как почти все программисты, ленив )

Comment: спасибо большое! вот только расписав это в ручном ввиде, я не понимаю как дальше рассуждать. Вот при вызове n = 7, F(7) = F(6) + G(5). И что дальше теперь? как рассуждать?

Comment: @Елена, если рассматривать логику с конца - каждый `return 1` будет в итоге просуммирован. Посмотрите внимательнее на вывод - вы увидите, что `return 1` напечатан 13 раз ;)

Comment: а кажется поняла, судя по консоли. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

А что тут объяснять? Берёте и смотрите, что происходит в функции `F` если её вызвать с аргументом `n = 7`. Какие она при этом вызовет функции и с какими аргументами. И т.д. В конце-концов придёте к вызовам функций `F` и `G` с аргументом `n = 1`, при этом сработает `return 1`, эта единица вернётся в места вызова `F(1)` и `G(1)`, в этом месте тоже что-то посчитается и вернётся и т.д. пока не дойдёте обратно до вызова `F(7)` и узнаете, что там вернулось. Просто берёте ручку и всё расписываете - и всё станет понятно.

Comment: ну вот я расписала на листочке, получилось, что при вызове n = 7, F(7) = F(6) + G(5). И что дальше теперь? как рассуждать?

Comment: @Елена Дальше, соответственно, расписываете что будет при вызове `F` с аргументом `6` и при вызове `G` с аргументом `5`. И т.д. Как будто подставляете математические формулы.

Answer (score 1):

если `n==2` или `n==1` обе функции возвращают 1. В противном случае они возвращают сумму значений возвращаемых еще двумя функциями (здесь это те же функции, но с аргументом уменьшенным на 1 и 2 соответственно).
то есть имеем такую последовательность вызовов:

```
f7 = f6+g5 
   = (f5+g4) + (g4+f3) 
   = ((f4+g3) + (g3+f2)) + ((g3+f2) + (f2+g1)) 
   = (((f3+g2) + (g2+f1)) + ((g2+f1) + (1))) + (((g2+f1) + (1)) + ((1) + (1))) 
   = ((((f2+g1) + (1)) + ((1) + (1))) + (((1) + (1)) +(1)))) + ((((1) + (1)) + (1))) + ((1) + (1)))) 
   = (((((1) + (1)) + (1)) + ((1) + (1))) + (((1) + (1)) +(1)))) + ((((1) + (1)) + (1))) + ((1) + (1)))) 
  = 13
```